# opencv 2.4.9, How can we get the same results with gpu::convolve and cv::filter2D?

Tags: c++, opencv, convolution, dft

I'm trying to use the opencv gpu module to filter an image with Gabor kernels. To check if everything is correct, I'm comparing the result of the CUDA accelerated filtering, with the regular CPU filtering. The code I'm using is available here: https://github.com/juancamilog/gpu_convolve_test.git

Since the funtcion cv::gpu::filter2D is limited to kernels of size smaller than 16x16, I'm using cv::gpu::convolve for larger kernels. In that case, I use cv::gpu::copyMakeBorder to produce a filter response that has the same size as the original image. gpu::convolve uses cuFFT to compute the convolution.

The problem I'm facing is that the result of the cv::gpu::convolve function is different from the result of cv::filter2D. What is the cause of this difference? How do we obtain a GPU filtering response that is the same as the CPU filtering response?

Some example results for the cv::gpu::filter2D case (no difference):

Original image (640x480)
[image: original]

CPU (13x13 kernel)
[image: using CPU filter2D]

GPU (13x13 kernel)
[image: using GPU filter2D]

And for the cv::gpu::convolve case:

CPU (25x25 kernel)
[image: using CPU filter2D]

GPU (25x25 kernel)
[image: using GPU filter2D]

Comment: I think that this happens because the cuda FFT API is expecting a kernel centered at (0,0): http://tinyurl.com/o8pyy9e. I can change the code to generate a kernel that has the same size as the image, shifted so the center is at pixel coordinate (0,0), perform the convolution with gpu::dft and gpu::mulSpectrums, and crop the result. Then the result is the expected one, although the computation time is much worse Maybe the fix is to modify the gpu::convolve code so that each block is convolved with a kernel centered at (0,0)?

Comment: Hi I am facing something similar. I am using the object detection GPU functions ( ORB) and i get different results for each run ( the matches). Some times results are good and sometimes there are a lot of false matches. Do you have an idea why and how i can fix it?